# How to have a list of unique Controllers in ListView.build

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating an application where I'm using [this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_pop_up_menu) to show custom pop-up menus in specific widgets. This plugin requires a controller so that it will be possible to hide the pop-up on click or whenever one needs to.

The controller works well for single widgets but never works for `ListView.builder`, because a single controller is replicated over and over again inside `ListView.builder`.

I have tried creating a model class that holds the  `CustomPopupMenuController` as shown in the code below.

```
import 'package:custom_pop_up_menu/custom_pop_up_menu.dart';

class MyCustomPopupController {
  CustomPopupMenuController controller;
  MyCustomPopupController({
    required this.controller,
  });
}
```

From there I'm creating an Instance of a List of `MyCustomPopupController` in my home screen as shown below

```
 List<MyCustomPopupController> controllers = List.empty(growable: true);
final CustomPopupMenuController _controller = CustomPopupMenuController();
```

Then when I'm creating my listView items, I'm trying to do this: Please only pay attention to this line on the code below:

`controllers.add(MyCustomPopupController(controller: "$_controller$loopIndex"));`

```
  void getAllMessages() {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
      List<SmsMessage> messages = await query.querySms(
        //querySms is from sms package
        kinds: [SmsQueryKind.inbox],
        //filter Inbox, sent or draft messages
        count: 200, //number of sms to read,
        address: "MPESA",
      );

      if (transactions.isNotEmpty) {
        transactions.clear();
      }

      if( controllers.isNotEmpty ){
        controllers.clear();
      }
      setState(() {
        //update UI
        allmessages = messages;

        for (var element in allmessages) {
          String message = element.body.toString();

          //print("$message\n\n");
          if ((RawData.getMode(message) == 1 ||
                  RawData.getMode(message) == 2 ||
                  RawData.getMode(message) == 3 ||
                  RawData.getMode(message) == 4) &&
              RawData.getTime(message) != 'ERR') {
            transactions.add(
              TransData(
                receiver: RawData.getReceiver(message),
                code: RawData.getTransactionCode(message),
                amount: RawData.getAmount(message),
                paymentMode: RawData.getModeName(message),
                time: RawData.getTime(message),
                date: RawData.getDate(message),
                phone: RawData.getSendMonmeyNumber(message),
                accountNumber: RawData.getPayBillAccountNumber(message),
                message: message,
              ),
            );

           controllers.add(MyCustomPopupController(controller: "$_controller$loopIndex"));
            loopIndex ++; 
          }
        }

        //List<CustomPopupMenuController> myConrollers = List.generate(loopIndex, (index) => controllers[index].controller);
        //print(myConrollers);
      });
    });
```

I'm trying to think figure out of away to add a unique controller with index from the this line:

`controllers.add(MyCustomPopupController(controller: "$_controller$loopIndex"));`

As you can see I was trying to append the loopPosition to the controller. I'm figuring out for a way to have unique name of a controller for all the looped items so that I can then use it on my popUp widget.

Comment: why don't you just add an unique value from your data..! I think there's must be some unique value in your data isn't it

Comment: I have tried that. The problem is I cannot concatenate objects. I can only concatenate strings. Kindly tell me how to append unique data to a specific object. Thanks